# Is it OK to wire routing-generale methods into the view?

Tags: symfony

many times I see, for example in Symfony:

html file:

```
<hr>
<?php $this->generateUrl('blog_show', array('slug' => 'slug-value')); ?>
<br>
```

this is a bad smell, like not using depencency injection: this way HTML is coupled to the current framework. I have to edit it if I want to move it to another framework.
Wouldnt it be better to just pass the generated url string from the controller?

Comment: There is no answer to this question, this is up to you to decide the limit between the logic and the view.

Comment: Is it bad smell? Tell it to the reactjs-developers ;)

Comment: I agree. The url should be generated in the controller and not in the view. The view is only for output not for any logic. separation of concerns.

Comment: "I have to edit it if I want to move it to another framework" 1. How often have you moved the same app from one framework to another?  2. How would moving this to the controller prevent you from having to make changes if you moved to a completely different framework controller with a different method for generating urls?

Comment: @Cerad of course its impossible to create a project that is 100% independent from the framework. I just said it can be more independent this way

Comment: Some would also argue that moving view specific logic into the controller is also a bit of a smell.

Comment: @Cerad, yea, this is when MVC is not enough, and another extra layer would be needed

Answer (score 1):

You can separate your view from your backend as you want, but your frontend file has to refer to an url at some point, even if it is just an api.

Changing your url from `<?php $this->generateUrl('blog_show', array('slug' => 'slug-value')); ?>` to `<?php $showUrl; ?>` just make it less maintainable and harder to migrate to another framework.

If you want to be Framework Independant you should use Symfony backend like an API.

Answer (score 0):

The url could be generated in the controller to separate model from view. But it's only a first step. The best way is to separate model, view and routing. I think the best way is to use a view helper which generates the path. I changed some framework for project (abandonware to symfony). It is easier when the project used a template (like Smarty or Twig)

Take a look at Symfony Twig extensions to have some example which separates path generation and controller.

As example, Twig purpose the path method. [This view helper](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#path) is searching the url path from the route paramter. It doesn't have any relation with controller or model.

> path : Returns the relative URL (without the scheme and host) for the given
>   route. If relative is enabled, it'll create a path relative to the
>   current path.

As you can see there you only have to be carefull to the route name.

```
/**YourController**/
/**
 * @Route("/foo", name="new-game", methods="get")
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function myFooAction()
{
    //Your code

    //The rendering without information about his own or other path
    return $this->render('default/foo.html.twig', []); 
}
```

And the corresponding path in Twig :

```
<hr>
<a href="{{ path('foo') }}" title="Alt">Some text</a>
<br>
```